# How to match only first occurrence using Regex

Tags: regex

I have this custom log event which has `Severity: HIGH` repeated twice in every event. I tried to use regex to match only the first occurrence and remove/replace it. Before remove/replace the first match I tried to select the first match, but my regex matches the both occurrences.

```
Host: Hostname
VServer: NO
Version: Oracle v11
Cause: SQL exception
Severity: HIGH
JDKPath:  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin
Process: 2816
Severity: HIGH
```

This is my Regex which matches both the occurrences `(Severity:)(.*)` or `(Severity:\s.*)`. How to match only first occurrence (i.e 5th line) not the second occurrence (i.e last line)?

Comment: You need to narrow your question down, and don't tag with every possible language. -1

Comment: Your `(Severity:)(.*)` pattern already works, you accepted an answer with an identical solution. Using modifiers totally depends on the regex flavor, none is indicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, it's not clear in which context you're using Regex (you tagged PHP and Python) but in PHP, it's quite simple:

```
/(Severity:.*)/
```

[**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/bX9fL2/2)

This works because by default, the `.*` token does not match a new line character. Since your `Severity` listings are on multiple lines, only the first line matches.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am using http://regexr.com/ which matches both the occurrences.

Comment: @Prime You will see both matches only if you leave the global flag, like `/.../g` which I don't have in my answer.  On RegExr, you need to remove that flag (flags option at the top right) to test my solution.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search):

> Scan through *string* looking for the first location where the regular expression *pattern* produces a match, and return a corresponding `MatchObject` instance. Return `None` if no position in the string matches the pattern; note that this is different from finding a zero-length match at some point in the string.

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> log = """Host: Hostname
... VServer: NO
... Version: Oracle v11
... Cause: SQL exception
... Severity: HIGH
... JDKPath:  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin
... Process: 2816
... Severity: HIGH"""
>>>
>>> m = re.search('Severity\: (.*)', log)
>>> m.groups()
('HIGH',)
```

As you can see, only the first one matched.

Conversely, if you use `re.findall` or `re.finditer`, then you get both:

```
>>> b = re.findall('Severity\: (.*)', log)
>>> b
['HIGH', 'HIGH']
>>>
>>> for f in re.finditer('Severity\: (.*)', log):
...   print f.groups()
...
('HIGH',)
('HIGH',)
>>>
```